# Context intent android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Sorry for my english. I have Activity1, Activity2 and java class. How i can in java class user intent for Activity1 -> go -> Activity2. For example

**Activity1**

```
new MyJavaClass(Activity1.this).goToActivity2();
```

**MyJavaClass**

```
 private Context context;
  public ProcessorApp(Context context) {
 this.context = context;
}

public void goToActivity2() {
 Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

**Activity2**

```
//hellow
```

i have error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
```

.

```
Intent i = new Intent((Activity)context, Activity2.class); //not work
Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class); //not work
```

Comment: you are passing intent for the same activity again in Activity2.  Also there is no startActivity too

Comment: add context as a parameter in your gotoActivity2 method

Comment: @VivekMishra thanks, but it not help me

Comment: @VivekMishra i cant understand, i sedn context `Activity1.this` to `MyJavaClass` and then try use `new Intent(context, Activity2.class);` why it not work. Im send context, what he want?)

Comment: your context is null that's why I am saying to pass it as a parameter

Comment: Can you give some more information about why you're calling the Intent from the MyJavaClass and not Activity1?

Comment: @VivekMishra thanks, i add as a parameters and then add `context.startActivity(i)` and it work!) Thanks

Comment: I told you before then you said it's not working, means you didn't tried then?

Comment: @Nick thanks, i add  `context.startActivity(i)` and it work)))

Comment: @VivekMishra yes, it not worked, if i only add `goToActivity2(Context context)` i need more add `context.startActivity(i)` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `startActivity(i)` in MyJavaClass to `context.startActivity(i)`.